# Calculate st.dev and mean for lists of lists with 1 value or 0

Tags: python, list, statistics

I have this list of lists:

```
fall_2_gpa = [[4.0, 3.4175, 3.1675, 3.2475, 3.25, 3.2475, 3.3325, 3.585, 3.5825, 3.3325, 3.5, 3.585, 3.8325, 3.165, 3.5025, 3.835, 3.5, 3.4175, 3.6675, 3.165, 3.25, 3.4175, 3.9175, 3.6675, 3.8325, 3.2475, 3.4175, 3.4175, 3.5825, 3.415, 3.5825, 3.585, 3.25, 3.4175, 3.6675, 3.3325, 3.5, 3.165, 3.3325, 3.6675, 3.6675], [3.5], [3.1675, 3.4175, 3.5, 3.6675, 2.5, 2.835, 3.585, 3.4175, 3.25, 3.4175, 3.1675, 3.75], [2.6675, 3.0], [3.0825, 3.665, 3.6675, 3.3325, 3.3325, 3.415], [3.3325, 3.415, 3.415, 3.415, 3.75, 3.75, 3.665, 3.6675, 3.6675, 3.5825, 3.5825, 3.9175, 3.4175, 3.6675, 3.5, 3.5825, 3.585, 3.6675, 3.665, 3.4175, 3.585, 3.4175, 3.415, 3.75, 4.0, 3.5, 3.6675, 3.25, 3.585, 3.3325, 3.4175, 3.5, 3.6675, 3.7525, 3.3325, 3.835, 3.335, 3.665, 3.5, 3.6675, 3.585, 3.75, 3.75, 3.5, 3.415, 3.0825, 3.6675, 3.2475, 3.2475, 3.335, 3.9175, 3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 3.585, 3.585, 3.4175, 3.25, 3.3325, 3.5, 3.25, 3.75, 2.835, 3.1675, 2.5825, 3.25, 3.5825, 2.915, 2.8325, 2.5, 3.0825, 3.3325, 2.8325, 3.25, 2.8325, 3.335], [3.5, 3.3325, 3.6675], [3.165, 3.4175, 3.4975, 3.25], [3.5825, 3.5, 3.4175, 3.75, 3.335, 3.335, 3.415, 3.5, 3.6675, 3.165, 3.6675, 3.4975, 3.9175, 3.6675, 3.4175, 3.25, 3.3325, 3.585, 3.835, 3.2475, 3.335, 3.75, 3.5825, 3.5, 3.4175, 3.5, 3.75, 3.5825, 3.585, 3.335, 3.5825, 3.5825, 3.3325, 3.75, 3.5, 3.6675, 3.3325, 3.5825, 3.4175, 3.415, 3.585, 3.75, 3.415, 3.4175, 3.25, 3.4175, 3.415, 3.415, 3.75, 3.9175, 3.8325, 3.665, 3.5825, 3.5, 3.585, 3.3325, 3.25, 4.0, 3.415, 3.1675, 3.7525, 2.5, 2.83, 3.0025, 2.5825, 3.25, 2.915, 3.0825, 2.75, 3.4175, 2.9175, 3.3325, 3.3325, 2.6675, 2.67, 2.75, 2.915], [3.25], [3.0825], [3.25, 2.4975, 2.915, 3.0, 2.75, 2.8325, 2.915], [3.6675, 2.8325, 3.165, 2.6675, 3.25, 3.4175, 2.5, 3.0825, 2.5825, 3.585, 3.0025, 2.9175], [3.6675, 3.6675], [3.5825, 3.585, 3.6675, 3.7525, 3.8325, 3.4175, 3.4175, 3.3325, 3.835, 2.9175], [3.335, 3.5025, 3.835], [2.9175, 2.5, 3.585, 2.9175, 3.0825, 2.665, 2.9175, 2.585, 2.7475, 3.25, 2.835], [3.0, 2.5, 3.5, 3.085, 3.75, 2.5, 2.75, 3.25], [3.5, 3.6675, 3.6675], [2.7525, 2.665], [3.415, 3.25, 3.5, 3.75, 3.415, 3.585, 3.4175, 3.4175, 3.415, 3.8325, 3.5825, 3.3325, 3.2475, 3.3325, 3.3325, 3.5825, 3.1675, 3.835, 3.415, 3.6675, 3.75, 3.2475, 3.4175, 3.4175, 3.4175, 3.665, 3.5825, 3.585, 3.6675, 3.5, 3.5, 3.415, 3.4175, 3.6675, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.585, 3.4175, 3.5, 3.415, 3.585, 3.585, 3.4175, 3.5825, 3.75, 3.5, 3.335, 3.5, 3.25, 3.5, 3.3325, 3.2475, 3.75, 3.75, 3.3325, 3.4975, 3.25, 3.4975, 3.4975, 3.5, 3.165, 3.585, 3.6675, 3.9175, 3.415, 3.5, 3.5825, 3.6675, 3.5, 3.5, 3.585, 3.5, 3.415, 3.25, 3.3325, 3.6675, 3.665, 3.585, 3.415, 3.6675, 3.4975, 3.585, 2.3325, 3.1675], [3.6675], [3.0825, 3.25, 3.5, 2.9175], [3.665, 3.5, 3.5825, 3.7525, 3.5, 3.585, 3.25, 3.3325, 3.6675, 3.585, 3.6675, 3.3325, 3.5825, 3.585, 3.6675, 3.5825, 3.0825, 3.6675, 3.585, 3.585, 3.3325, 3.0825, 3.5, 3.415, 3.5, 3.4175, 3.4175, 3.3325, 3.7525, 3.6675, 3.4175, 3.75, 3.3325, 3.25, 3.585, 3.5, 3.5825, 3.1675, 3.4175, 3.5, 3.4975, 3.4975, 3.4175, 3.6675, 3.25, 3.6675, 3.415, 3.6675, 3.335, 3.415, 3.4175, 3.4175, 3.835, 3.5825, 3.1675, 3.6675, 3.585, 3.25, 3.4175, 3.5825, 3.5825, 3.415, 3.1675, 3.415, 3.6675, 3.5, 3.585, 3.585, 3.335, 3.5, 3.3325, 3.5, 3.4175, 3.1675, 3.4175, 3.5, 3.585, 3.5, 3.67, 3.7525, 3.8325, 3.6675, 3.5, 3.665, 3.75, 3.585, 3.75, 3.4175, 3.75, 3.335, 3.665, 3.3325, 3.5825, 3.6675, 3.75, 3.415, 3.165, 3.5825, 3.665, 3.585, 3.5825, 3.335, 3.5, 3.335, 3.6675, 3.0825, 3.4175, 3.4975, 3.3325, 3.3325, 3.6675, 3.335, 3.0825, 3.0, 2.915, 2.75, 3.9175, 3.2525, 2.9175, 3.085, 3.335, 2.75, 2.915, 3.5, 3.0, 2.915, 2.5825, 2.665, 2.5825, 2.8325, 2.7475, 2.915, 2.75, 2.9175, 2.165, 3.6675, 2.6675, 2.6675, 3.0825, 3.585, 3.2525], [3.5825, 3.5825], [3.335, 3.0825, 3.1675, 3.3325], [3.1675], [3.4175, 3.4175, 3.5, 3.3325, 3.1675, 3.25, 3.5, 3.5, 3.25], [3.3325, 3.415], [3.5825, 3.1675, 3.9175, 3.585, 3.4975, 3.25, 3.5, 3.5, 3.665, 3.415, 3.4175, 3.415, 3.5, 3.415, 3.5, 3.165, 3.9175, 3.3325, 3.165, 3.5, 3.6675, 3.3325, 3.415, 3.5, 3.25, 3.6675, 3.165, 3.4175, 3.5, 3.585, 3.5, 3.4175, 3.5825, 3.585, 3.4975, 3.3325, 3.3325, 3.5, 3.5, 3.4175, 3.4975, 3.8325, 3.415, 3.4175, 3.165, 3.5, 3.3325, 3.6675, 3.415, 3.5, 3.5825, 3.585, 3.585, 3.335, 3.415, 3.6675, 3.415, 3.3325, 3.25, 3.585, 3.5, 3.25, 3.25, 2.75, 3.5825, 3.0, 2.58, 2.8325, 2.915, 2.9175, 2.835, 2.9175, 3.5, 2.665, 3.335, 2.3325, 2.665, 3.335], [3.5, 2.835, 3.0, 2.5, 3.25, 3.0, 3.2525, 2.5825, 2.6675, 2.835, 3.0025, 2.5, 2.6675, 3.5825, 2.835, 2.6675, 2.8325, 2.8325, 2.835, 2.5, 3.085, 3.25], [3.335, 3.335], [3.415, 3.415, 3.415, 3.3325], [3.8325, 3.5025, 3.3325, 3.335, 3.585, 3.75, 3.415, 3.5, 3.5825, 3.25, 3.75, 3.4975, 3.6675, 3.835, 3.6675, 3.9175, 3.415, 3.5, 3.5, 3.3325, 3.5, 3.25, 3.3325, 3.165, 3.4175, 3.3325, 3.415, 3.5825, 3.6675, 3.5825, 3.75, 3.665, 3.3325, 3.415, 3.25, 3.25, 3.4175], [3.75, 3.6675, 3.5, 3.25, 3.25, 3.585, 3.5, 3.4175, 3.3325, 3.5825, 3.25, 3.5025, 3.5, 3.665], [3.6675, 3.75, 3.3325, 3.2475], [2.9175, 2.415, 3.75, 3.0, 3.5, 3.165, 3.4175, 2.8325, 2.835, 2.9175], [3.335, 3.585, 3.6675, 3.4175, 3.415, 3.9175, 3.3325, 3.5, 3.4975, 3.415, 3.0825], [3.2475, 3.8325, 3.6675, 3.5825, 3.3325, 3.5825, 3.5025, 3.585, 3.6675, 3.5825, 3.6675, 3.5825, 3.5825, 3.4175, 3.835, 3.835, 3.585, 3.5, 3.5, 3.3325, 3.9175, 3.5, 3.4975, 3.67, 3.835, 3.585, 3.5, 3.75, 3.2475, 3.75, 3.415, 3.5, 3.0825, 3.585, 3.5, 3.0825, 3.6675, 3.6675, 3.665, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.4175, 3.6675, 3.5, 3.835, 3.5825, 3.585, 3.3325, 3.3325, 3.1675, 3.0, 3.6675, 3.4175, 3.5, 3.335, 3.5, 3.585, 3.9175, 3.5825, 3.165, 3.5, 3.2475, 3.2475, 3.415, 3.5825, 3.25, 3.4175, 3.5, 3.75, 3.3325, 3.25, 3.5825, 3.75, 3.4175, 3.8325, 3.415, 3.5825, 3.4175, 3.25, 2.835, 3.33], [3.75, 3.6675, 3.5, 3.25, 3.4175, 3.415, 3.5825, 3.665, 2.75, 3.1675], [3.585, 3.5, 3.3325, 3.3325, 3.585, 3.5, 3.5025, 3.7525, 3.5, 3.5, 3.665, 3.3325, 3.585, 3.5, 3.25, 2.835], [3.5825, 3.4175, 3.75, 3.5, 3.6675, 3.4175, 3.4175, 3.0825, 2.75], [3.4175, 3.5825, 3.585, 3.3325, 3.5, 3.25, 3.25, 3.5, 3.9175, 3.5, 3.835, 3.5825, 3.415, 3.5825, 3.4175, 3.5, 3.585, 3.2475, 3.165, 3.5, 3.75, 3.5825, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.4175, 3.6675, 3.415, 3.25, 3.585, 3.25, 3.6675, 3.75, 3.3325, 3.335, 3.1675, 3.665, 3.25, 3.3325, 3.4175, 3.5, 3.6675, 3.415, 3.835, 3.415, 3.0, 3.165, 3.4975, 3.8325, 3.3325, 3.5825, 3.2475, 3.5, 3.75, 3.835, 3.335, 3.1675, 3.6675, 3.585, 3.6675, 3.5, 3.4175, 3.335, 3.3325, 3.0825, 3.3325, 3.4175, 3.415, 3.4175, 3.4175, 3.5825, 3.665, 3.25, 3.415, 3.25, 3.5825, 3.2475, 3.415, 3.5, 3.165, 3.665, 3.3325, 3.75, 3.3325, 3.5825, 3.585, 3.8325, 3.75, 3.6675, 3.415, 3.335, 3.415, 3.75, 3.3325, 3.25, 3.4175, 3.4175, 3.0825, 3.6675, 3.8325, 3.25, 3.335, 3.585, 3.415, 3.0825, 3.5825, 3.7525, 3.4175, 3.6675, 3.5025, 3.5, 3.33, 3.6675, 3.335, 3.5825, 3.0, 2.665, 3.0825, 2.7525, 2.9175, 2.835, 3.085, 2.665, 2.915, 2.75, 2.4175, 2.9175, 3.0, 2.75, 3.5825, 2.835, 2.5825, 2.9175, 3.085, 3.0825, 3.085, 2.75, 2.5, 3.085, 3.165, 3.0825, 2.835], [3.25, 3.6675, 3.6675, 3.5825, 3.415, 3.67, 3.415, 3.1675, 3.3325, 3.75, 3.415, 3.5], [3.5825, 3.4175, 3.3325], [3.585, 3.5], [2.75, 3.4175, 2.665, 3.165, 2.415, 3.5, 2.8325, 3.0], [3.5, 3.5825, 3.5025, 3.165, 3.3325, 3.5825], [3.5025, 3.8325, 3.5825, 3.585, 3.585, 3.6675, 3.3325, 3.4175, 3.25, 3.3325, 3.3325, 3.3325, 3.3325, 3.665, 3.5825, 3.165, 3.5, 3.0825, 3.6675, 3.5825, 3.5, 3.4975, 3.665, 3.4175, 3.5, 3.3325, 3.585, 3.835, 3.835, 3.5, 3.5, 3.75, 3.4175, 3.3325], [3.3325, 3.5, 3.4175, 2.915, 3.25, 3.3325, 3.25, 2.8325, 2.915, 3.4175, 3.665, 2.9175, 2.915, 2.835, 2.8325, 2.75, 2.8325, 2.9175, 2.665, 3.6675, 2.8325, 2.5825, 3.165, 3.2525, 3.25, 3.3325, 2.8325, 2.9175, 3.165], [3.3325, 3.585], [2.9175, 2.5, 3.1675], [3.75, 3.25, 3.4175, 3.75, 2.8325], [3.665, 3.3325, 3.5, 3.5825, 3.5, 3.4175, 3.5, 3.6675, 3.4175, 3.335, 3.1675, 3.5825, 3.415, 3.6675, 3.415, 3.6675, 3.335, 3.75, 3.5, 3.1675, 3.4175, 3.25, 3.6675, 3.75, 3.25, 3.6675, 3.25, 3.4175, 3.5825, 3.585, 3.5, 3.75, 3.3325, 3.585, 3.3325, 3.75, 3.3325, 3.5, 3.665, 3.9175, 3.3325, 3.665, 3.415, 3.8325, 3.6675, 3.6675, 3.165, 3.5, 3.4175, 3.5, 3.75, 3.4175, 3.3325, 3.585, 3.5825, 3.4175, 3.665, 3.25, 3.415, 3.6675, 3.3325, 3.25, 3.585, 3.5825, 3.5, 3.5025, 3.6675, 3.4175, 3.8325, 3.33, 3.6675, 3.7525, 3.6675, 3.5, 3.4175, 3.585, 3.25, 3.4175, 2.5825], [3.0, 2.5], [3.5], [3.1675, 3.4175, 3.9175, 3.165, 3.25, 3.2475, 3.75, 3.6675, 3.4175, 3.585, 3.5825, 3.5825, 3.6675, 3.165, 3.6675, 3.5, 3.5825, 3.5, 3.25, 3.5825, 3.67, 3.25, 3.6675, 3.6675, 3.5825, 3.0825, 3.415, 3.5, 3.5025, 3.585, 3.585, 3.6675, 3.33, 3.585, 3.5, 3.6675, 3.3325, 3.0], [3.585, 3.5825, 3.4175, 3.335, 3.5, 3.585, 3.1675, 3.665, 3.0825], [3.415, 3.5825, 3.4175, 3.7525, 3.5825], [3.5, 3.3325, 3.3325, 4.0, 3.25, 3.75, 3.6675, 3.415, 3.5825, 3.75, 3.25, 3.6675, 3.75, 3.7525, 3.415, 3.3325, 3.9175, 3.6675, 3.4175, 3.5, 3.4175, 3.4175, 3.75, 3.585, 3.5825, 3.5825, 3.5825, 3.165, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5825, 3.4175, 3.4175, 3.585, 3.5, 3.3325, 3.75, 3.4175, 3.5, 3.5025, 3.75, 3.585, 3.4175, 3.415, 3.4175, 3.5825, 3.585, 3.165, 3.5025, 3.5, 3.5825, 3.5, 3.8325, 3.5, 3.5, 3.75, 3.67, 3.5, 3.4975, 3.8325, 3.4175, 3.585, 3.585, 3.5825, 3.5, 3.1675, 3.4175, 3.5, 3.165, 3.5, 3.7525, 3.4175, 3.415, 3.5, 3.9175, 3.3325, 3.4175, 3.75, 3.3325, 3.415, 3.5, 3.5025, 3.5825, 3.585, 3.75, 3.25, 3.5, 3.5825, 3.6675, 3.5825, 3.5, 3.3325, 3.5825, 3.1675, 3.5, 3.3325, 3.6675, 3.25, 3.4175, 3.3325, 3.5025, 3.585, 3.4175, 3.415, 3.2475, 3.0825, 3.585, 3.25, 3.5825, 3.585, 3.835, 3.3325, 3.415, 3.3325, 3.6675, 3.8325, 3.6675, 3.4175, 3.6675, 3.3325, 2.5825, 2.5825, 3.5, 3.085, 3.0025, 2.5, 2.8325, 3.0, 2.75, 2.67, 2.75, 2.5825, 2.5825, 2.5, 3.585, 2.335, 2.9175, 3.585, 3.25, 3.3325, 2.58, 2.75, 2.3325, 3.0825, 3.2475], [3.9175, 3.5, 3.5825, 3.25], [3.5, 3.25, 3.415, 3.5825, 3.415, 3.5825], [3.6675], [3.6675], [3.4175, 3.585, 3.2475, 3.5825, 3.75, 3.5, 3.6675], [3.25, 3.4175, 3.5, 3.4175, 3.0825], [3.75, 3.25, 3.7525, 3.5025, 3.75, 3.3325, 3.6675, 3.5825, 3.4975, 3.7525, 3.6675, 3.25, 3.5825, 3.165, 3.75, 3.4175, 3.25, 3.3325, 3.665, 3.5825, 3.165, 3.835, 3.3325, 3.5825, 3.5, 3.835, 3.5825, 3.5, 3.585, 3.5, 3.415, 3.6675, 3.585, 3.165, 3.585, 3.5, 3.4175, 3.335, 3.415, 3.4175, 3.3325, 3.5825, 3.3325, 3.1675, 3.25, 3.5825, 3.5825, 3.6675, 3.5825, 3.665, 3.5, 3.5825, 3.5, 3.5, 3.585, 3.3325, 3.4175, 3.5, 3.6675, 3.835, 3.4175, 2.415, 2.75, 2.8325, 3.0825, 3.6675, 3.0, 3.0, 3.25, 3.1675, 3.165, 3.165, 4.0, 2.3325], [3.665, 3.6675, 3.3325, 3.585, 3.6675, 3.6675, 3.6675, 2.8325, 3.4175], [3.5, 3.335, 3.4975], [3.3325, 3.4175, 3.3325, 2.25, 3.835, 3.335, 3.4175, 2.5825, 2.5825, 3.0025, 3.1675, 2.7525, 3.5825, 2.75, 2.5, 3.0825, 3.2525, 3.085, 3.085, 3.6675, 2.8325, 2.6675, 3.3325, 3.3325], [3.335, 3.4175], [3.25, 2.75, 2.75, 3.0025, 3.0, 3.0825, 3.0], [3.415]]
```

and I am trying to calculate the mean and standard deviation like this:

```
mean_fall_2 = [statistics.mean(d) for d in fall_2_gpa if d != 0]
stdev_fall_2 = [statistics.stdev(d) for d in fall_2_gpa if d != 0]
```

but I keep getting this error:

> statistics.StatisticsError: variance requires at least two data points

I believe I get this because some sublists have only 1 value and not more than 2. For another list I get this error:

> statistics.StatisticsError: mean requires at least one data point

which probably means that it found an empty sublist?

Is there a way to solve those issues? I need st.dev and mean to be calculated for everything, with no exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fall_2_gpa list contains some lists of size 1 which is being passed to statistics.stdev() function. However, statistics.stdev() expects argument to have at least two items. Therefore, we can add a condition to check the size of list while processing the list items as:-

```
stdev_fall_2 = [statistics.stdev(d) for d in fall_2_gpa if d != 0 and len(d)>1]
```

And in similar way, we can also instruct the function to use some default value whenever there's list of size less than 2.

Use the following for adding 0 on else condition:

```
stdev_fall_2 = [statistics.stdev(d) if d != 0 and len(d) > 1 else 0 for d in fall_2_gpa]
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to return 0 in such case? because i need all the values to be passed in a way to stdev_fall_2.

Comment: hi @piggy, I have added the else condition to return 0 in such cases. Hope, it will help

Comment: It is exactly what I wanted! Thank you so much! @nandal